# Proper ActiveRecord associations for self-joined classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have been modifying an online Rails tutorial to suit my specific needs, and I've found myself out of my depth. A little clarity would be much appreciated. My code is below my question.

At this point, if `dan` and `rob` are instances of class `User`, and I call

`dan.add_supervisor(rob)`

then it returns an empty collection:

```
dan.supervisors
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Yet the supervision itself has been created:

```
dan.initiated_supervisions
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Supervision id: 50, supervisor_id: 68, supervisee_id: 67, created_at: "2015-03-10 18:30:01", updated_at: "2015-03-10 18:30:01">]>
```

The ideal behavior would be for the `has_many :through` behavior to work properly, and to be able to get a list of Dan's supervisors by calling `dan.supervisors`. What changes do I need to make to have that happen?

**User.rb**

```
...

# Supervisees can choose their supervisors, 
# but not the other way around.

has_many :initiated_supervisions,     class_name: "Supervision", 
                                      foreign_key: "supervisee_id", 
                                      dependent: :destroy
has_many :non_initiated_supervisions, class_name: "Supervision", 
                                      foreign_key: "supervisor_id", 
                                      dependent: :destroy

has_many :supervisees, through: :non_initiated_supervisions
has_many :supervisors, through: :initiated_supervisions

...

def add_supervisor(other_user)
  initiated_supervisions.create(supervisor_id: other_user.id)
end

...
```

**Supervision.rb**

```
...

belongs_to :supervisor,    class_name: "User"
belongs_to :supervisee,    class_name: "User"
validates  :supervisor_id, presence:   true
validates  :supervisee_id, presence:   true

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution (for the time being...please, oh please keep working...) is specifying `class_name: "User"` in two of the `User` model associations:

```
has_many :supervisors, through: :initiated_supervisions, class_name: "User"
has_many :supervisees, through: :non_initiated_supervisions, class_name: "User"
```